# Pyinstaller dist file creates unused numpy pyd and dll files

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, import, pyinstaller

I've used Pyinstaller to create an executable. The file is 80MB, 21 of which are from the numpy-atlas.dll file. However, my code does not use the numpy import.

It does have matplotlib.pyplot, but I was under the impression that only .pylab would contain numpy. Here are my imports.

I assume I am just being dense.

```
import os
import pickle
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import periodictable as pt
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Comment: Matplotlib needs numpy. Also pandas is based on numpy.

Comment: Alright, I will have to live with it then. Thank you for the fast response.